# Google script inverses day and month from the google form

Tags: forms, events, google-apps-script, calendar, inverse

I am creating a google calendar will contain birthdays in it. To make it automatically, I created a form and a script that would automatically create the vent and repeat it every year.

I get a problem that I just can't understand: the day and the month get inversed in the calendar.

The code is made by 2 files, one that contains the function that creates the event and the other is triggered when the form is submitted. The dates are also saved in a google spreadsheet. Here is the code:

Create the event:

```
function createBirthdays_ ( namedValues ) {
    var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( "Anniversaires CA" )[0].createAllDayEventSeries(namedValues.Nom, new Date ( namedValues.Date ), CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule());
}
```

The function that gets triggered when the form is submitted:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    createBirthdays_ ( e.namedValues );
}
```

I am sure it is something really simple, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might it be that in one of them you get European date format and in the other the US? There the month and day are in different order. So you might want to try to process namedValues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just checked and the form, the spreadsheet and the calendar are all in the same format (dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: Humor me and convert it to mm/dd/yyyy before adding to the calendar.

Comment: I don't have the time right now unfortunately but I'm pretty sure this will work so I'm putting it as the correct answer! Thank you!